# how can i populate my viewmodel's property with collection in it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

These are my main class

```
public class Customer
{
  public Customer()
  {
    Products = new HashSet<Product>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

These are my view models

```
public class ProductVM
{
  public string ProductName { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerVM
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public ICollection<ProductVM> Products { get; set; }
}
```

How can I populate the properties of `CustomerVM`?

Something like this I have tried:

```
var tmp = _db.Customers.Select(c => new CustomerVM
{
  Name = c.Name,
  Products = ????? // I don't know how to populate here
}
```

Really new in `asp.net mvc` and `linq` still making my way up.

Comment: You can't, since your Customer object doesn't seem to have any products!  Without looking at your database we can't tell.  How does your database associate customer and products?  Presumably there is some other table that joins Customers and Products.

Comment: how is your `Customer` and `Product` entities connected ?

Comment: I have updated my question. So sorry, forgot about their relationship. A `Customer` can have many `Products` I only want to display the `Customer`'s Name and the associated `Products` with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the `Products` property and Create a collection of `ProductVM` from that using the `Select` keyword like this

```
var customerVm= _db.Customers
                   .Select(c => new CustomerVM
                                {
                                  Name = c.Name,
                                  Products = c.Products.
                                                  Select(s => 
                                    new ProductVM {ProductName= s.ProductName}).ToList()
                                });
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
var tmp = _db.Customers.Select(c =>
    new CustomerVM
    {
        Name = c.Name,
        Products = c.Products.Select(p => new ProductVM { ProductName = p.ProductName }).ToList()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `Products` is already populated in the `Customer` :

```
Products = c.Products.Select(p => new ProductVM() { ProductName = p.ProductName } ).ToList()
```

If not :

```
Products = _db.Products.Where(p => p.CustomerId = c.Id)
    .Select(p => new ProductVM() { ProductName = p.ProductName } ).ToList()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make your ICollection in the Customer Class and the Customer in the Product class virtual you will have them linked automatically.

```
public class Customer
{
  public Customer()
  {
    Products = new HashSet<Product>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string ProductName { get; set; }

  public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

if you do so you can fill the dots with c.Products